# storing date working in local but not working in Server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using `commentedTime  : {type: Date, required: false, default: Date.now()}` in model to store present date. I am not sending the date value in payload. in local it was storing present date but in Server it was storing `22-12-2020`. I can't understand why it is happening.

please help me with answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `new Date()` instead of `Date.now()`

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass `Date.now` as a function to the default value.
Your model looks like the below.

```js
{
  commentedTime  : {type: Date, required: false, default: Date.now}
}
```